# How to see what process on iPad/iPhone is using data?

Tags: ipad, data

I have my iPad using shared WiFi from my Mac. It's not plugged in, nothing's updating, nothing's open. But unless I have it on airplane mode I see it draining all the bandwidth from my Mac. Is there some app or settings view that shows what processes are using bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

On an unjailbroken device you can't see this information.

On iOS 7, you can only see cellular data usage ( Settings > Cellular network > Usage )

Maybe you could just try to kill one by one the apps that are running in background.